# Upgrade Postgres standby replica using rsync

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, replication, rsync

I have some doubts about the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) which states the following:

> 11. Upgrade streaming replication and log-shipping standby servers
>
> If you used link mode and have Streaming Replication (see Section
> 27.2.5) or Log-Shipping (see Section 27.2) standby servers, you can follow these steps to quickly upgrade them. You will not be running
> pg_upgrade on the standby servers, but rather rsync on the primary.
> **Do not start any servers yet.** (...)

Does it mean exactly what is says? After upgrading a primary server I can't even turn it on to check wheter everything works fine? Upgrade of standby won't be possible then? If so, why?

Second question, can I upgrade **delayed replica** this way? (based on archive command WAL shipping and recovery_min_apply_delay setting) or the WAL files are incompatible between major versions and only possibility is to setup it from scratch using basebackup? (and lost these delayed WALs)

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts are justified. I [suggested an improvement](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/22f129004bb66cd91e1dfd3345a9787f5039f3ae.camel%40cybertec.at) to this part of the documentation a while ago, but that never came to pass. I want to bring Robert Haas' comment to your attention:

> Also, let me express my general terror at the idea of anyone actually
> using this procedure.

I think that this is more a guideline for a PostgreSQL expert than a cookbook for the average end user. My recommendation is to rebuild the standby from scratch.

But let me answer your specific questions:

- Yes, you should do that *before* you start the primary. The idea is that there should be as few modifications as possible, so that the `rsync` is as fast as possible. Even starting and stopping PostgreSQL will modify the data directory.
- No, that won't work with a delayed replica. You should let the standby catch up before you `rsync` it to keep the `rsync` time minimal. Even if you don't do that, the standby will not be delayed any more after `rsync`.

Comment: So about delayed replica its clear as day now, but regular replica, it's only matter of time? It will just take longer if I turn on primary for a moment? I bet it will be still at least several times faster than basebackup (taking into account DB is few hundred GBs)

Comment: Probably. But why would you want to start the primary? Surely you run a test upgrade earlier.